# How to create a Karma/Jasmine unit tests to check Angular service that depend on other module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have read a lot of articles and I still don't understand how to create it.

There is a module (“A”) that has service (“B”) that has function (“C”). The function is using another function (“E”) in other module(“D”). I want to test the behavior of the function (“C”), with different answers from function (“E”), [true, False, etc...]

Example:

`angular.module('A',[]) // or angular.module('A',['D'])
.service('B', function(){
this.C = function() {
    return !D.E() ;
  };`

I built the app with Yeoman Angular generator

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming everything lives under one module say A.

```
angular.module('A',[])
  .service('B', function(D) { // Using Dependency Injection we inject service D here
    this.C = function() {
      return !D.E();
    }
    return this;
  })
  .service('D', function() {
    this.E = function() { return false; };
    return this;
  });
```

Unit Test:

```
describe('Unit Test for the Service B', function() {

  var B, D;  

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('A');
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function(_B_, _D_) {
    B = _B_;
    D = _D_;
  }));

  describe('Functionality of method C', function() {

    it('should negate the returned value of the method E in service D', function() {
      var E = D.E();
      var C = B.C();
      expect(E).toBeFalsy();
      expect(C).toBeTruthy();

    });
  });
});
```

Lets say that it lives in a different module - module Z.

```
angular.module('A',['Z']) // Now we include the module Z here
      .service('B', function(D) { // and again using Dependency Injection we can inject service D here.
        this.C = function() {
          return !D.E();
        }
        return this;
      });
angular.module('Z', [])
      .service('D', function() {
        this.E = function() { return false; };
        return this;
      });
```

Unit Tests:

```
describe('Unit Test for the Service B', function() {

  var B, D;  

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('A');
    module('Z');
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function(_B_, _D_) {
    B = _B_;
    D = _D_;
  }));

  describe('Functionality of method C', function() {

    it('should negate the returned value of the method E in service D', function() {
      var E = D.E();
      var C = B.C();
      expect(E).toBeFalsy();
      expect(C).toBeTruthy();

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, It's very helpful. The last point that I still don't know, it's how can I manipulate the answer from pseudo E, to test the different behavior of C with different answer from E.